# passing variable to this particular sed command

Tags: unix, sed, csh

I am first searching for a key word and once that key word is found in a file from that particular line i am supposed delete till end of file.

```
#! /bin/csh -f
set sa = `grep -n -m 1 "^Pattern" file`
set s = `echo "$sa" | cut -d':' -f1`   
set m = `sed '$s,$d' file | tee see > /dev/null`
```

so first line gives me the matching line with line number, second line i am getting the line number and third line i am trying to delete from line $s say 20 till last but it is not working. I have tried all combinations but it does not take the variable $s. Please help.

Comment: You know that variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes, don't you? This is Shell Scripting 101.

Comment: i already tried but it then does not identify $d.

Comment: Why did you tag this `bash` when you're using `csh`?

Comment: Better question: why are you writing a script in csh? http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `$s` out of the quotes so it will be expanded.

```
set m = `sed $s',$d' file | tee see > /dev/null`
```

Comment: Sorry for tagging bash. It worked. Actually this is one of the several part of script which i am implementing in csh.

Answer (score 2):

But you can do it much more easier with a single line of `sed`:

```
sed -n '/SEARCHPATTERN/q;p
```

1. `-n` tells to not print the lines
2. `/SEARCHPATTERN/q` exits on search pattern
3. `;p` otherwise print the lines